# How to recover an old keyring in ascii format?

Tags: gnome-keyring, binary, ascii

some recent system upgrade messed up my passwords keyring, by changing the Default keyring's format from ASCII to binary.

The old text file was moved to my Desktop and a new empty binary one was created in ~/.local/share/keyrings, so all saved password are lost!
I tried to copy an import the old one to the same folder, but the ASCII format is not recognized by Seahorse.
How can I import or convert the old keyring into the correct binary format?

Here is a sample of the entries I find in the ASCII keyring:

```
[keyring]
display-name=Default keyring
ctime=1648331716
mtime=0
lock-on-idle=false
lock-after=false

[29]
item-type=0
display-name=Password for 'SessionData' on '***'
secret={"api_url": "https://***", "appversion": "*", "cookies": {"Session-Id": "***", "Tag": "vpn-b"}, "session_data": ***
mtime=1697985464
ctime=1697985464

[29:attribute0]
name=application
type=string
value=Python keyring library

[29:attribute1]
name=service
type=string
value=***

[29:attribute2]
name=username
type=string
value=SessionData

[...]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: *"after changing the Default keyring's format from ASCII to binary"* how, exactly? please [edit] your question with more context

Comment: I don't know how. I just found out that in ~/.local/share/keyrings there was a new keyring file I could not open by a text editor, since it's in some binary format. The old keyring that I found moved to Desktop was a text file instead.